# My ecommerce site isn't displaying price anymore

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

Hello again dearest Experts,

I have an ecommerce site at http://www.millenniumhealthproducts.com

The site was working very well using Access as backend database.
Recently, we changed hosting company to godaddy.com.

We migrated the data from Access to SQL Server database and of course changed connection string to point to SQL Server db.

Since then, the site now display price as 0.00.

I can't figure out what is causing this.

The fieldname is cprice. On Access db, the datatype is Currency and on SQL Server, it is Money.

What one strange thing that I noticed is that on the SQL Server db, the value is more like xx.xxxx.

Example 299.0000 while on Access db, the value is more like $299.00

Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

Could changing connection strings have anything to do with it?

I can provide some sample asp code if requested. I am using classic asp.

```
'Response.Buffer = true
Dim catid, strcat
catid = Request.QueryString("id")
strcat = Request.QueryString ("cat")

If catid = "" OR (IsNumeric(catid) = false) Then
    Response.Redirect "index.asp"
End if

Dim catname, productslist
sub productInfo(connObj,category)
    q = chr(34)
    set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = connObj
    cmd.CommandText = "qryProdsCategory"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    set param = cmd.CreateParameter("theCategory",adInteger,adParamInput,4)
    cmd.Parameters.Append(param)
    cmd("theCategory") = Cint(category)
    set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    set rs = cmd.Execute

    if not rs.EOF then
        catname = rs("catdescription")
    %>
        <table width='100%' border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr>
     <%
        i = 1
        while not rs.EOF
           id = RS("catalogID")
           'Response.write id
           'response.end
        %>
         <td class=bodytextcolor width='33%' align=center nowrap>
         <img src="img/small/<%=rs("cimageurl")%>" align="center" WIDTH='97' HEIGHT='125'>
         <br/><%=rs("cname")%>
          <br>Regular Price: <font color=red><%= FormatCurrency(rs("cprice"),2) %></font>
         <br/><font color=green>10 or more:</font>
         <font color=red><%=FormatCurrency(rs("cover10price"),2)%></font>
         <br/><font size=-1><a href="product.asp?id=<%=id%>">View Details</a></font>
         <br/>
         <font face="Verdana">
        <form name="_xclick" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="millennium2000@charter.net">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%=rs("cname")%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= FormatCurrency(rs("cprice"),2) %>">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity: <input maxLength="6" Name="quantity" size=2 value="1" style="height: 2.2em; border: 1px solid Black; background: ButtonFace;">
          <input type="image" src="images/button_in_cart.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
          <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
         </form></td>
       <%

            if (i mod 3) = 0 then
                Response.write "</td></tr>"
            end if
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        wend

    else
        Response.write "Product information not found."
        catname = "Error"
    end if
        Response.write "productslist: "
    rs.Close
    set rs = nothing
    set cmd = nothing

end sub

%>

--stored procedure
USE [scartmil]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[qryProdsCategory]    Script Date: 02/12/2012 19:08:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[NewStoredProcedure]    Script Date: 02/10/2012 19:36:49 ******/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[qryProdsCategory](@theCategory int)
AS
SELECT products.*, products.ccategory, categories.catdescription
FROM categories INNER JOIN products ON categories.categoryID = products.ccategory
WHERE (((products.ccategory)=@theCategory));

GO
```

Comment: In SQL server, what is data type? Money? Better provide your code where data is binding.

Comment: My first guess would be with the datatype differences. Probably somewhere in your code that handles the price, the mangling is resulting in a default 0 value being taken and used.

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt response. I have posted code above.

Comment: You need to show the text of the procedure `qryProdsCategory`. Also much of the ASP code you're displaying is largely irrelevant. Actually, probably all of it. But, is it possible that you have moved the web site too, and it is now on a server with different regional settings (e.g. , instead of . for decimals)?

Comment: I think you need to adjust FormatCurrency(rs("cover10price"),2). I guess FormatCurrency always return 0.

Comment: Aaron, I really thought about what you said about much, if not all of the ASP stuff being irrelevant. I  would like to rewrite and would greately appreciate your assistance. I have posted the qryProdsCategory procedure above. It used to be Access query but I did my best to change it to SQL Stored proc. It may have been better using VIEWS instead of procedure, now that I think about it.

Comment: And what happens when you don't use the FormatCurrency function to display the price?

Comment: nothing displays, not even the 0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When migrating from Access to SQL you face a number of conversion issue's, i believe your issue is at the migration level and the field in SQL would either be `money` or `numeric(18,2)`, you may have to either remigrate it or see if SQL will keep the values if you change the datatype of field.

Also, make sure any IDENTITY datatypes are also configured in SQL, Access to SQL doesn't really take care of this too well, from experience at least.

Comment: As you can see from my original post, I changed to sql server data type of Money and it is showing values like 989.0000. I will try numeric now and see if it helps. FYI, I did try decimal(18,2)

Comment: the money field does this because of the SCALE defined in SQL, that's why i usually use `Numeric(18,2)`  the `2` is the Scale = places after the decimal point.

Comment: Zee, I tried that but unfortunately, no help - still same 0.00

Comment: when does it change to 0.00, during the conversion or in the app??

Comment: in the app. It shows the correct amount on the db after conversion. Only difference I notice is that let's say the amount is $48.00 in Access db, it shows as 48.00 in SQL. This, after changing datatype to currency(18,2)

Comment: Also, have you considered using this in your SQL when requesting the data from the DB? `CONVERT(Numeric(18,2), ROUND(moneyField,2))`

Comment: If the data is `48.00` in the db, how is that NOT what you want?

Comment: No, I didn't say that's not what I want. I said it still shows as 0.00 on the app and I am trying to see if you can kindly help me figure out why it is showing 0.00 on the app. I have spent all day on this today and still can't figure it out.

Comment: Does the Stored Procedure return the correct value? ie `48.00`

Comment: yes. for instance, this is one of the values returned by the stored proc - 1150.00

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7597/discussion-between-zee-tee-and-chidi-okeh)

Comment: As it is always the case, the solution is right in front of you and usually simple but hard to see when you are under the gun. I just had to assign them variables like cprice= rs("cprice") and that's it. It is working now. I don't know why it has to be done only in price but not other items. Thanks for sticking through this as long as you have.